# Unsupported Atomic Operation in OpenCL

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl

I am Using Atomic operations for OpenCL. same code is working for intel CPU but is giving error on Nvidia GPU. I have enabled Atomics for 32 bit and 64 bit both.

```
     int cidx=idx%10;

     int i=1;
     C[idx]=In1[idx] & In2[idx];
     atomic_add(R,i);
```

This is just portion of overall code. its giving build error "Unsupported Operation"  While running on Nvidia Quadro GPU rather it's working all fine on Intel i3, Xeon, and AMD Processors.

Comment: Is R volatile and an integer pointer in the local or global workspace?

Answer (score 0):

atomic_add did not appear in OpenCL 1.0, it was added in a later revision of the spec. You might be running on two different implementations which conform to different OpenCL versions.